# AFNetworking Examples won't compile - Module 'AFNetworking' not found

Tags: afnetworking

I just downloaded the AFNetworking zip file.
I first compiled the AFNetworking Xcode project.
Then I changed the Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework location in the Example project (to point to the appropriate Derived Data framework directory) and  tried to compile the examples.  However, I still get the compile error:

Module 'AFNetworking' not found.

I have tried adding the framework to the framework search path in the build settings, but that didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you install the  pod after download ? might me be its require pod install .

Comment: Yes, I install cocoa pods and opened the xcworkspace instead of the projects, and I can now compile and run the examples.  Thanks!

Comment: I've ran `pod install` and have the `workspace` opened, but I'm getting `/ios-audiofetch-sdk-sample/AudioFetch-SDK-Sample/AudioFetch-SDK-Sample-Bridging-Header.h:5:9: Module 'AFNetworking' not found`